# Computer not booting when Hard disk is connected

Tags: hard-drive, cpu, bios

I bought a new system with Seagate 2 TB internal hard disk about a week ago.

I have Windows 7 running on my PC. Till yesterday my system working fine.

Today when I tried to start my system, I see the Intel logo and press F2 for bios and F10 for Boot menu. It does not move from there. I am not able to access BIOS Setup.

I did not get any error message.

- The BIOS is accessible if I remove the hard disk. If i connect hard
  disk it does not run beyond the Intel logo.
- I connected my hard disk to another system, it boots and works fine.
- I tried other hard disks (500gb & 1TG Seagate) in my new system; they
  boot and work fine.

Any ideas?

Intel I5 3470
Intel DH77EB
2TB Seagate
16 GB (8*2) RAM
2GB Graphic Card

Comment: What else changed between the systems? Maybe USB cables, power connectors?

Comment: Only Hard disk was interchanged......

Comment: It's clearly "not right" so if it's new, get a replacement!

Comment: @Rohit Dave is correct, it's up to the manufacturer/seller (legalities depending on the country you're in) to fix this.

Comment: when you say you bought a new system, was it used (but 'new to you') or brand new from a store? did you try different sata positions, like sata2, sata3 or sata4? another thing i would check is if the bios is up-to-date even though this really should be a factor in this situation.

Comment: It's a new system, i bought the parts from different shop and i have assembled it. i have tried with different sata positions nothing helping me out.

How do i update the Bios?